# POST Request not working using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I tried implementing ajax post request in laravel 4, but I am unable to obtain the post data. I have tried implenting both input::get() and input::all().

Here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url :url,
    type:'POST',
    data:{username:username},
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);  
    }
});
```

Controller Class code:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    // Obtain the response text
    protected function _make_response( $response_str, $type = 'application/json' ) {
        $response = Response::make( $response_str );
        $response->header( 'Content-Type', $type );
        return $response;
    }

    // User Login Function 
    public function loginAction()
    {
        // $setting_name = Input::get( 'username' );
        $username = Input::get('username');

        $response = array(
            'username' =>$username,
        );

        return $this->_make_response( json_encode( $response ) );
    }}
```

I am not able to paste the image here. So I am pasting the result that obtained from Firebug.

```
 POST http://localhost/d/dthKerala/public 200 OK 117ms  
 Object {...}
```

But I change the request Type to **GET**. I am able to obtain the data.

```
 GET http://localhost/d/dthKerala/public?username=render  200 OK 119ms  
 Object {username="render"}
```

How can I be able to obtain POST data ?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made is sending data with a field value pair called  => . Just change data to have a name "username" with value `username`

```
    $.ajax({
    url :url,
    type:'POST',
    data:{"username":username},
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);  
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what's the result of `var_dump($_POST);` on your ajax page?

Comment: If using your underwater screen (f12 in chrome for instance) could you inspect the data send during an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax(
 {
    url :url,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:{'username':username},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you be able to specify your route portion 
Also I would like to suggest to use Response::json() instead of writing more line of codes:

```
 public function loginAction()
   {
        return Response::json(array('str'=>$response_str))
   }
```

Comment: Route::any("/", [
     "as"   => "user/login",
     "uses" => "UserController@loginAction"
]);